# Warning: move_uploaded_file(); failed to open stream

Tags: php, file, move

I'm trying to upload image using `move_uploaded_file();`

```
$target_dir = "product_images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["product_image"]["name"]);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) { // Line 92
    echo "<script>alert('The file " . basename( $_FILES["product_image"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.')</script>";
    die();
}
```

So when I try to execute this code I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(product_images/img_forest.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/suvenirshop/admin_area/insert_product.php on line 92

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpZEJdEV' to 'product_images/img_forest.jpg' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/suvenirshop/admin_area/insert_product.php on line 92
```

I'm using xampp on linux, I also tried this code on windows pc and mac where I get the same error.
I have to mention that I have folder product_images in folder where I stored insert_product.php which execute this code.

Comment: `Permission denied` check permissions of the `product_images`

Comment: Thanks you that worked i changed permissions on folder for all to be read and write and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to give write permission on product_images folder . In terminal goto the folder where product_images folder created by   `cd` command and then `chmod a+w product_images` command on Linux systems